# boost mpi reduce for std::complex<long double> array

Tags: c++, boost

Does anybody out there have idea about doing reduce for `std::complex<long double>` array using boost?

I am getting error `‘struct std::complex<long double>’ has no member named ‘serialize’`
 for following code:

```
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
#include<complex>
namespace mpi = boost::mpi;

int main() {
mpi::environment env;
mpi::communicator world;
const int N = 4;

std::complex<long double>  a[N]={};


 if (world.rank() == 0) {
    std::complex<long double>  sum[N] = {};
    mpi::reduce(world, a,sum, std::plus<>(), 0);

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++) std::cout<<a[i]<<std::endl; 
} 

}
```

I compiled it using `mpic++ main.cpp -o main  -lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization -lboost_system`

Answer (score 0):

A common design in libraries that can optionally use foreign types like the SC++L ones, types from a modern standard you may not have, or types from other sources is to not provide the functionality unless you explicitly include a header.

Boost does this for Fusion and Serialization, to avoid pulling in heavy SC++L headers for things you may not desire in your translation unit, or which may not even exist.

It is highly likely that there exists a header like `boost/serialization/complex.hpp` you may need to find and include.